# asp.net mvc where to put structures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple structure (`struct`) which I want to place in my asp.net `MVC` application.

```
public struct QuantityAndSize
{
    public decimal quantity;
    public string size;
}
```

A `struct` is not really a model and it isn't a view or a controller either.
Maybe I shouldn't use structs in the first place, so where should I place it or should I avoid it.

**EDIT**

This question is not performance related. The main purpose of this question is to get the Structure of the project correct so that it will meet best practice

Comment: If it semantically belongs alongside the models, why do you think it shouldn't go there?  If you have some other semantic grouping of code then why not make a folder to hold that group?  It's not really clear why this is a problem...

Comment: It stores the quantity and the size of an object. For example I have an object and Order for a Board. The User wants to buy 2 Boards of the size 50cm

Comment: The user fills in a Form where he places the order. The order is then stored in the model and will be send via email

Comment: So you **are** using it as a model? Again, why did you decide on using a struct?

Comment: It is a piece used inside a model. So i guess it belongs to the model but it isn't a model for itself

Comment: A part of a model is still a model. If you don't have compelling reasons to use a struct, use a class.

Comment: @CodeCaster okay I thought it would be more fancy like placing it in some sort of extra directory or something but placing it alongside the models seems to be valid to I guess. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on use cases. You have to answer yourself why you have used `struct` in the first place.

Personally I find structs rather exotic beings in my web applications because of the fact than they are immutable. The good example of using struct is introducing a `Range<T>` structure, which can be used as generic range to prevent creating similar beings in my code. Each range should be immutable and I want each to be unique - it seems like a good use case.

I don't see any good use cases when interacting between layers in MVC and I don't see any real use case when introducing some business concepts. On the other hand, if you want to gather some values into one and use it as a value type, using `struct` is perfectly fine IMO.